# Dynamic Data Site: can't hide a table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I've created a new web site based on the 'Dynamic Data Site' template. Three tables were added into it: Product, ProductSKU, and SkuPrice. There are relationships between tables:

```
Product.ProdId = ProductSku.ProdId
ProductSku.SkuId = SkuPrice.SkuId
```

I don't want the user to see 'Product' table, so I've hidden that table:

```
namespace CompanyDbAdmin
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetadata))]
    public partial class Product
    {
    }

    [ScaffoldTable(false)]
    public class ProductMetadata
    {
    }
}
```

When I tried to hide some columns in the 'ProductSKU' table:

```
namespace CompanyDbAdmin
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ProductSKUMetadata))]
    public partial class ProductSKU
    {
    }

    public class ProductSKUMetadata
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public object MyCollumnName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've discovered that didn't work: the column is still displayed. The problem seems like the 'ProductSKU' class is not 'matched' to existing table...

Here is auto-generated code for that table:

```
namespace CompanyDbAdmin
{

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="SotiModel", Name="ProductSKU")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class ProductSKU : EntityObject
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Attempt to hide this table with

```
namespace CompanyDbAdmin
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ProductSKUMetadata))]
    public partial class ProductSKU
    {
    }

    [ScaffoldTable(false)]
    public class ProductSKUMetadata
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public object MyCollumnName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Doesn't work either: The table still exists on the first page...

Why? How can I fix that?

Comment: What happens if you place `ScaffoldTable(false)` directly on `ProductSKU` class?

Comment: Didn't try that. Does it make any sense?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as a duplicate (link above) as the author of the question has confirmed that the linked question solved the issue (self answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to that question: *[Partial class doesn't match to auto-generated class part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032535/partial-class-doesnt-match-to-auto-generated-class-part) resolved the current one either*

The problem was in in Visual Studio: it didn't consider the entity class as a partial class... And as a result, it didn't apply metadataclass to the entity class.